# Add More form does not get reset after submit in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngualrJS with Java from webjar library. I have one form which having 3 fields - name, desc and quantity. It is using as add more, add more items. Below is similar code I am using.

```js
 angular.module("ngApp").controller("taskController", function($scope) {
   $scope.submitted = false;
   $scope.item = {};
   $scope.items = [];

   $scope.submitTask = function(item) {
     $scope.items.push(item);
     $scope.submitted = false;
     $scope.itemForm.$setPristine();
     $scope.itemForm.$setUntouched();
   };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="taskController">
  <form name="itemForm" ng-submit="submitted && submitTask(item)" novalidate>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="item.name" required/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="item.description" required/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" ng-model="item.quantity" required/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here `$scope.submitted` is set false in `$scope.submitTask`. But in view it shows are true. Even `$scope.itemForm.$setPristine()` and `$scope.itemForm.$setUntouched()` gives error as undefined.

Please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit: *Be careful not to cause "double-submission" by using both the ngClick and ngSubmit handlers together. *

Comment: try this  `$scope.itemForm = [];` in `submitTask`  function